# ERROR TypeError: this.memberListRef is undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

i'm trying to use ionic5 Form with Firebase. As depicted below, this form contains some input texts like member name, dob, email etc. ive generated **member page** along with m**ember service** and **member interface** and already configured environment. When i run the app, i got this error **ERROR TypeError: this.memberListRef is undefined**.

Please find the code scripts below.

**member.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Member } from '../shared/member';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MemberService {
  memberListRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  memberRef: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  // Create
  createMember(apt: Member) {
    return this.memberListRef.push({
      member_name: apt.member_name,
      member_dob: apt.member_dob,
      member_email: apt.member_email,
      member_club_id: apt.member_club_id,
      member_contact: apt.member_contact,
      member_address: apt.member_address

    })
  }
.
.
.
.

   }
```

and this is my **add-member.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { MemberService } from './../shared/member.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-member',
  templateUrl: './add-member.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-member.page.scss'],
})
export class AddMemberPage implements OnInit {
  memberForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private aptService: MemberService,
    private router: Router,
    public fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.memberForm = this.fb.group({
      member_name: [''],
      member_dob: [''],
      member_email: [''],
      member_club_id: [''],
      member_contact: [''],
      member_address: ['']
    })
  }
  formSubmit() {
    if (!this.memberForm.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.aptService.createMember(this.memberForm.value).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        this.memberForm.reset();
        this.router.navigate(['/club']);
      })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  }

}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you're trying to "memberListRef.ONE_METHOD()" on a non-initializated "memberListRef" object....but without more code it's diffiult to say more.

Comment: Thanks @emandt, i will share full code.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this error is to define memberListRef before push

```
createMember(apt: Member) {
    this.memberListRef=this.db.list('member')
    return this.memberListRef.push({
      member_name: apt.member_name,
      member_dob: apt.member_dob,
      member_email: apt.member_email,
      member_club_id: apt.member_club_id,
      member_contact: apt.member_contact,
      member_address: apt.member_address
    })
  }
```